# Prove that $m$ is a torsion element.

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $M$ be a $\mathbb Z$-module and consider $M \otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Q$. Then $m\otimes q = 0$ for some $q \in \mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$, if and only if $m$ is a torsion element.

The "if"  direction is quite straightforward: if $m \otimes z = 0$, then:
$$m\otimes q  = m \otimes \frac{zq}{z}=zm\otimes \frac{q}{z} = 0$$

The other direction is where I'm having trouble: I have shown that if $ q = a/b$ Then:
$$\begin{alignat}{}
  m \otimes q = 0
&\Rightarrow \quad m\otimes\frac{a}{b} = 0
\\&\Rightarrow \frac {abm}{b}\otimes\frac{1}{b}= 0
\\&\Rightarrow abm \otimes 1= 0
\end{alignat}$$
Does this necessarily imply that $m$ is a torsion element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $m\otimes q=0$ for nonzero $q\in\Bbb Q$ iff $m\otimes1=0$
in $\Bbb Q$.

We can construct a module isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ by a localisation
construction. Define an equivalence relation on $M\times\Bbb N$ as follows:
$[m,t]\sim[m',t']$ iff $t'm-t'm$ is torsion. It's routine to prove it's
an equivalence relation, and that $[m,t]+[m',t']=[mt'+m't,tt']$ defines an
addition on the equivalence classes making them into a group $M'$.
This is a $\Bbb Q$-module, and $\phi:m\mapsto[m,1]$ is a homomorphism from
$M$ to $M'$. Then $\phi$ induces a map from $M\otimes \Bbb Q$ to $M'$
and if $m$ is non-torsion, then $\phi(m)\ne0$ and as this is an image
of $m\otimes1$ then $m\otimes 1\ne0$.

Comment: Perhaps in the first line you mean $m \otimes q = 0$ ?